# Salmon cooking time

Tags: cooking-time

What is the best method for determining when salmon is cooked? I usually just eyeball it and look at the color and texture but some of my friends use a cooking thermometer? I was wondering if there were some advantages for using one method over the other.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of determining whether the salmon is raw or not, each method is equally effective (assuming that your “eyeball judgement” is sound). However, if you want to fine-tune the degree to which the salmon is cooked (medium-rare, well-done, etc.) then I would suggest using an instant-read thermometer. It takes a little bit longer than the eyeball approach but if you care about how well your salmon is cooked then it’s worth it.